# changing system time with Python

Tags: python, datetime, subprocess, popen

so i need some Python code to allow a user to adjust the system/hwclock on a raspberry Pi (part of a bigger programme). The below code works in a fashion and allows me to alter the time, although only if I'm changing the time forwards, if I alter it backwards for some reason, whilst it does update the time the programme the just hangs, it never gets to the last print line. Assuming (but don't know why) its timing out but why does it work forwards....?

```
import subprocess
import time
import os

whattime = input ("What's the new time? ")
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'timedatectl', 'set-ntp', 'false'])
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'timedatectl', 'set-time', whattime])
print("clock time changed, it's now ", whattime)
```

Now after much reading and mainly 'trial & error' I got it to work both ways by changing the code to this:

```
import subprocess
import time
import os


whattime = input ("What's the new time? ")
subprocess.run(['sudo', 'timedatectl', 'set-ntp', 'false'])             
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'timedatectl', 'set-time', whattime], start_new_session=True)
print("clock time changed, it's now ", whattime)
```

I stumbled onto this 'fix' and not sure why its really fixed it, or just masked the issue and I've just built up another problem having sub-process left running or something in background? Any help would be appreciated - Thanks.

Comment: I can't think of any reason why `start_new_session=True` would be relevant to this.